# How to decode access token from Microsoft OAuth2

Tags: cakephp, oauth-2.0, active-directory, jwt, microsoft-graph-api

I am building a web application using CakePHP 4.1.

And it has authorization from Microsoft Active Directory(OAuth2).

What I am going to do is to decode the access token and redirect to Microsoft login page when it is expired.

So I can get token from authorization like this.

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&response_type=token&redirect_uri=LOGIN_REDIRECT_URI&response_mode=form_post&scope=offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'`

I tried to decode using `firebase/jwt`, but I am not sure what should be `$key`.

```
JWT::decode($accessToken, $key, array('RS256'))
```

I can get the decoded result if I enter the token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms)

I don't have any special `claims`, so `$key` should be `plain`.

And I want to know if there is another way to decode jwt.

Comment: *I don't have any special claims, so $key should be plain* - what do you mean by that, what special claims do you mean, what is a plain key and how is it related to claims?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase JWT only supports decoding with signature validation, so a key is always required.

You can manually decode the token, it's just JSON as base64, however without validation there's no way to know whether the information hasn't been forged, so I wouldn't trust any information obtained that way, not even the expiration time.

Usually OAuth APIs return an expiration time in the response for access token requests (and [**so does Microsofts Identity Platform API**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#successful-response-1)), which your app can store alongside the token and use for checking for possible token expiration.

Refreshing upon receiving invalid token errors from the API is usually an option too, then you don't need to care about the expiration time yourself at all.

I would certainly suggest any of those options over trusting arbitrary client data.

That being said, if you still want the unvalidated expiration time from the token, just do what Firebase JWT does internally:

```php
$tks = \explode('.', $accessToken);
if (\count($tks) != 3) {
    throw new \UnexpectedValueException('Wrong number of segments');
}
list($headb64, $bodyb64, $cryptob64) = $tks;
if (null === ($header = JWT::jsonDecode(JWT::urlsafeB64Decode($headb64)))) {
    throw new \UnexpectedValueException('Invalid header encoding');
}
if (null === $payload = JWT::jsonDecode(JWT::urlsafeB64Decode($bodyb64))) {
    throw new \UnexpectedValueException('Invalid claims encoding');
}
if (false === ($sig = JWT::urlsafeB64Decode($cryptob64))) {
    throw new \UnexpectedValueException('Invalid signature encoding');
}
```

**https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/blob/v5.2.0/src/JWT.php#L81-L94**

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.